# How do I clear the temporary list after iteration

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to construct clusters in a way that each minimum x found, we gather the corresponding points and construct an element of a cluster x3:[x1,x2].

for this, I use a list to store the corresponding points then insert them for each element of a hashmap.

The problem is that the temporary list is updated for all the elements giving me something like

```
3 [4, 2, 5, 1, 0]
4 [4, 2, 5, 1, 0]
```

while the intended result is

```
1 [ 1, 0]
3 [3]
4 [4, 2, 5]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Double> E = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    HashSet<Integer> dataPoints = new HashSet(); 
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> clusters = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(); //list of corresponding points for each xmin
    System.out.println("size one :" + dataPoints.size());

    while (!E.isEmpty()) {
      int xMin = getKey(E, MinX(E, dataPoints));
      System.out.println("you re " + xMin);
      dataPoints.add(xMin);
      l.add(xMin);
      System.out.println("Xmin " + xMin);
      E.remove(xMin);
      //checking id X exists in data points if no  return  close elements
      for (int j = 0; j < S.getRow(xMin).length; j++) {
        if (!dataPoints.contains(j) ) {
          if (S.getEntry(xMin, j) > beta) {
            System.out.println(j);

            dataPoints.add(j);
            l.add(j);
            E.remove(j);
          }
        }
        clusters.put(xMin, l);
      }
    }

What am I missing
```

Comment: please format your code with proper indentation and add definition of all relevant variables (like `E`). in short, a complete and reproducible example

Comment: Do you mean that I should  add all of the variables and functions ?

Comment: `.clear()` method will empty your array list. add it where you want your list to be empty

Comment: I ve tried it but I ended up with empty clusters, as it is updated with the last elements i get **3 []
4 []**

Comment: Because you use single letter variable names, it is pretty hard to understand what you are actually trying to do. What are E, l, and S? What are they actually supposed to represent. But you at least use the same List (l) for all values. So it is not surprising that that is the same for all. Create a new List for each minimum value.

Comment: E is entropy, S is similarity , and l is the list in which ii store the found points for each datapoint

Comment: when creating a list for each iteration isnt that gonna be costy .?

Comment: You need a new list for each entry in the HashMap. So for your example result, you need three lists.

Comment: I'm parsing a file , so when the case for a huge file, there will be optimization issue i guess rught ?

Comment: Well, because your code is not very understandable, it is hard to say whether you will get performance issues or not. And because it is unclear what task you are trying to achieve it, how your input data looks like, what it represents, and what your output data means, it will be not be possible to suggest any improvements. But, it seems clear that your output is some kind of HashMap from Integers to some kind of lists of Integers. In order to get that output you will have to create a separate list for each HashMap entry. No amount of optimisation will change that.

Comment: Rewrite your code first such that it works and is understandable. Then if you have performance issues, and cannot solve them yourself, post a new question, explain what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried to solve the performance issues.

Comment: that did the thing , thanks